# Getting null while trying to retrieve rowid in fts3

Tags: android

I'm stuck at this for last 5-6 hours. Nothing is working. I want to get key corresponding to a user entered query so that user can modify the data corresponding to that particular id.

Is something wrong here in this code..??

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " USING fts3 (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ADDRESS
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_BALANCE + " DOUBLE);");
```

I'm getting this KEY_ID column empty. I want to get this id (using cursor element like we use cursor.getString(int) ) to let the user modify the values corresponding to the chosen id so I need to get the id from somewhere. Is there any way to call the default ID of fts3 table rather than using an alias?

Comment: What is the value for `KEY_ID` and what is your query?

Comment: KEY_ID = "_id"
I want to get the unique ID which is defined for each row.

Comment: I tried to access the default ID defined by fts3 table but that didn't work so I tried to create an alias but that column is empty. I don't know why. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to call the default ID of fts3 table rather than using an alias?

The problem is that Cursors used in Adapters *must* have an integer primary key column with the name `_id`, but `_id` is not a recognized alias by SQLite. So no, you need to use your own alias. You can use `docid as _id`, `rowid as _id`, etc.

---

**Addition**
Since I don't believe you can alter the `docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column in anyway inside the `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` statement, you will need to apply the alias in the `SELECT` statements, for example:

```sql
SELECT docid as _id, bar FROM Foo WHERE bar MATCH 'John';
```

Comment: & Sam.. in my table there're separate columns for _id & the default id (which appears as 'docid' btw).. That's why I'm getting an empty column. :/

Comment: Where are you trying this, in `CREATE TABLE`? If you read [Creating and Destroying FTS Tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2), you'll discover that anything aside from a column name is "pure syntactic sugar", meaning it is ignored... So I don't believe you can create an alias in the `CREATE` statement, you use the alias in each `SELECT` statement.

Comment: That is not an FTS table. This is the problem: regular tables honor `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, but FTS interprets `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as `_id` (a regular column) and will _always_ use `docid` as the primary key...

Comment: Okay. Then.. is there anyway to get that key corresponding to some element of the same row.. KEY_NAME (say)..??

Comment: I mean.. given a name can I find its position?

Comment: Please tell me.. I'm stuck at this for last 6-7 hours now. :|

Comment: I mean.. I can get it done but I think that method can generate inappropriate results in future..:/
I can use a static int & increase it every time I get a new entry.

Comment: Okay that will return a cursor.. then how will I get that id for that row using that cursor like we access other columns using cursor.getString(int).. How can I apply this method to get the id..?

Comment: Okay, I think it'll be 0th column then.. K.. I'm trying this then.

Comment: I'm very thankful to you. You just saved a lot of time. Thanks. :)

Comment: Though still.. Can I not increment my column _id.. I don't need that.. Thanks..:)